# Rotate object texture

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I have created this sign, but when I added the red texture to the face, the texture turned out sideways. Is there a way to rotate it? The original image is the right way up.

[image: Rotated stop sign]

In the texture settings there doesn't seem to be a rotation value.
[image: Texture settings]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way of doing it with simple (non-UV) texture mapping, is to tweak the mapping coordinate and scale.

[image: 1a]

For example:

- Switching X and Y axis, and scaling X by -1 will rotate the texture 90 degrees clockwise.
- Switching X and Y axis, and scaling Y by -1 will rotate the texture 90 degrees counter-clockwise.
- Scaling X and Y by -1 will flip the image vertically.

But you see that it's quite limiting, less intuitive and flexible than UV-map based rotation, described in gandalf3's answer.

Answer (score 17):

You need to UV unwrap it:

1. Enter edit mode and select all (<kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Unwrap the mesh. For that flat plane the best way is probably aligning your view to the face of the sign (<kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> with the face selected) and pressing <kbd>U</kbd>*> Project from view*.
3. Then select the UV coordinates in *Texture > Mapping*:

   [image]

You should be able to rotate the UV map in the *UV image editor* with <kbd>R</kbd> to adjust the rotation.

See the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Unwrapping) for more information.

## Cycles:

Note that in cycles it's possible to rotate the texture without UV unwrapping via the *Mapping node*:

[image]

Comment: The texture was applied with a material the doesn't seem to be any setting for rotation

Comment: @qwertie In that case you haven't unwrapped your sign yet. There is a way to rotate it, (I'll update my answer) but I recommend UV unwrapping it (see [the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Unwrapping)).

Answer (score 3):

Image Sampling > Flip X/Y Axis

[image: image sampling > flip x/y axis]

Comment: Need more context. Where is this in the UI?

Comment: @foobarbecue it's an old answer so probably this feature may have been removed with cycles, but on Blender Render the panel is located typically on the right "Properties/Texture" panel with "Type" set to "Image or Movie"... the fix in Cycles is to adjust the "Scale" to "-1"

Comment: Using a mapping node and adjusting the scale to -1 as Eli stated works perfect, just be sure the image node is set to "Repeat" and not "Clip". Otherwise, a negative scale produces a black output.