# EZ uv-mapping of generated images to sphere, but never the right direction

Tags: uv, node-editor

I'll be generating images in python and then uv-mapping them to a sphere and hope to automate it - possibly even a new image each frame coordinated with the sphere shape keyframed as well. uv-mapping was quite easy when I [did it here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43844/5334) with a NASA image, but when I tried again with PNG images that were saved using `plt.imsave('img2', img2)` blender seems to want to put the "poles" somewhere on the equator.

**update:** The [NASA images](http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view.php?id=73909) don't work now either. I recently moved to a new computer environment (clean install) and installed the most recent Blender.

Below are the images shown a few ways to make sure I have the orientations in both "tall" and "wide" format. The shapes of the numpy array generating the images are `[1201, 2401, 4]` and `[2401, 1201, 4]` where the third index represents R, G, B, A.  The pattern is calculated so that the lines are constant thickness from "equator" to "pole" after uv-mapping to a sphere.

I used the GUI to make the first sphere and set the parameters, connected the Nodes material, then copy/pasted a second sphere and edited the image file. I haven't rotated the spheres at all.

While I can **half-fix** this by adding a [mapping node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5609/5334) as @Gandolf3 shows, I really want the direction of the lines to reliably map to the top and bottom of the uv-sphere mesh object - being the place where all the edge loops meet.

Is there some way I can get Blender (here) to always uv-map the *long edges* of the image, or at least the *top/bottom edges* reliably to the poles of the uv-sphere? If I do this a lot I may try to automate it, and images may differ in size/shape slightly I'd like to get a handle on this!

Here are [img2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkRbl.png) and [img3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVPpe.png) to play with!

**Nodes:**

[image: Nodes uv-mapping start]

**uv-spheres**

[image: not rendered spheres]

**Rendered:**

[image: rendered spheres]

**the two images**

[image: original images]

**This Doesn't Help!** (all permutation of x, y, and z 90deg rotations)

[image: Doesn't Help!]

Comment: unwrap the object and use UVs as the texture coordinate instead of generated

Comment: Have you tried rotating on the other axes in the mapping node?

Comment: @Matt yep, all eight combinations 0 or 90 for x, y, z rotation. some 180's and 270's also. The whole pattern responds by rotating but with no change in the shape of the pattern. This is similar to what happens when I rotate the images during generation first (red vs blue).

Comment: @cegaton I'm looking to automate this, and therefore looking for a more streamlined solution than unwrapping all the time (frame-by-frame for each new image? ouch!) Thanks for reminding me - I should add that to the question. Since it *used to work* (see edit) for the NASA images  - I'd like to find out how to generate images that work the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem the next day when the coffee was fresh and it's somewhat of an oversight, but since I found it I'll just post it here.

The *Projection* setting in the *Image Texture node* needs to actually be set to `Sphere` if you want to project on to a Sphere. Makes sense :).

[image: Solved!]